# Is it possible to capture AVTP packets with tcpdump?

Tags: android, tcpdump, automotive

I'm new to Automotive Network. I am trying to capture some AVTP (IEEE1722) protocol packets on an Android device. Is it possible to capture AVTP packets with tcpdump on Android? I heard someone said tcpdump can only capture network layer packets, but AVTP is a transfer layer protocol. Does this means it's impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> tcpdump can only capture network layer packets

This is not true. tcpdump and friends can capture ethernet and 802.11 frames, which are at layer 2 while the network layer is layer 3 in the OSI model.

tcpdump will copy bytes going over the network interface that it has access to, regardless of protocol, for layers >= 2. It looks like [AVTP (IEEE1722)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Video_Bridging) is a layer 2 protocol, like ethernet. You can check what interfaces tcpdump sees with `tcpdump -D`.

For sample packet captures (8) of this protocol, you can use https://tshark.dev/search/pcaptable/ and search for protocol `ieee1722`. Wireshark uses the display filter `ieee1722` for this protocol ([ieee1722 filter reference](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/i/ieee1722.html)).